# Magento server admin in Australia?

Tags: magento2, server-setup

Our business is going to start using M2. We are going to get a dedicated server for it but have no idea how to set it up for Magento.
Is there a company that can set up the server for optimal use for M2 and provide any server maintenance and support?

Our host said they can set it up but I rather trust someone that has experience in Magento. The other option is to go for a host that specialise in magento but the price is more than double.

Comment: Welcome to Magento Stack Exchange :). Better to go with AWS

Answer (score 1):

### If you want to manage your server

If you have an IT team who can setup, manage and deploy then AWS will be your best value.  We use AWS for all of our magento hosting and have been very pleased with the results

We put a priority in CPU over RAM as magento tends to hog up CPU resources more so than RAM.  The instance types we like are c4.large and c4.xlarge:
http://www.ec2instances.info/?selected=c4.large,c4.xlarge

Through AWS you'll have the ability to setup an [elasticache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) redis server, a [mysql rds](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) for db and [load balancer](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) with [auto scaling group](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/).  Also using php7 will give you a big improvement in performance.

AWS is extremely powerful, but make sure your team is comfortable with it.  If you guys are new to AWS, then you should experiment with it first before doing any production hosting.

Keep in mind if you are going to setup and manage your own hosting, make sure that it is PCI compliant; mainly make sure db is on a separate server than application.

Magento also has a [whitepaper](https://magento.com/sites/default/files/White%20Paper%20-%20Magento%202.0%20Performance%20and%20Scalability%2003.31.16.pdf) that discusses other methods of increasing performance.

### If you do not want to manage your server

If you prefer not to do the tech/maintenance yourself and are on enterprise, magento now provides a [hosting solution](https://magento.com/products/enterprise-cloud-edition).  I have not yet had a site that uses the solution, but if money is not an obstacle (their hosting tends to be pricey) they'll take care of all the optimization, maintenance and deployments for you.

For other solutions, you can check out Magento's [hosting technology partners](https://magento.com/partners/portal/directory/?partner_type=6&partner_region=filter_all&specializations%5B0%5D=Hosting).

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't have a team so I don't think AWS is an option. 
I kinda just want someone to set up a server for me and then lean on them if we have any server issues.
There are magento hosting services, how different are they compared to a regular host? I'm finding it hard to spend double the money for this.